# Starcraft 2 - 2 part question about resource feeding in 2's and ranking system

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What exactly is a “cheese” in Starcraft 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1724/what-exactly-is-a-cheese-in-starcraft-2)
>   [StarCraft 2 - why haven't certain players been promoted to higher leagues?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11393/starcraft-2-why-havent-certain-players-been-promoted-to-higher-leagues)

Part 1: feeding and cheesing.  Is feeding in a 2v2 game considered cheese?  I played a few with a buddy (we are high bronze), and he has been feeding me resources as Terran while I go mass blink stalkers, w/ 3rd tier upgrades if the battle takes some time.  Is that cheese or is it legit?

Part 2, the upgrades/matchmaking system.  We are in high bronze in 2v2, and win well over 60% of the games we play.  Recently I've been checking the ranks of the people we beat, and we have been beating golds, silvers, and a few plats (we stomped a middle-ranked plat team with the feeding strategy).  So, why aren't we getting promoted to silver (at least)?  Any info on either of these questions is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You should probably break this up into two separate questions.   They aren't really related.

Comment: sorry, they seemed related to me at the time of posting, but in hindsight they do seem unrelated.

Comment: Your second question really needs to be re-worded as well. As of now it is too localized. You should re word it to asking how the matchmaking system works - and make a second question as stated by Billare.

Comment: 1) Feeding your friend means hurting yourself, turning it into a 2v1 essentially. I would guess this wouldn't really fly in gold or platinum. Possible duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1724/what-exactly-is-a-cheese-in-starcraft-2 2) Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11393/starcraft-2-why-havent-certain-players-been-promoted-to-higher-leagues

Comment: Regarding 1: It's not a 2v1 by all means. If you have enough production facilities and your ally provides you with lots of resources, you can produce an army that is bigger or equal the size of the opponents army. In addition all your units gain from the same updates and you create one big Protoss death-ball. Definitely a viable strategy even in higher levels.

Comment: Btw: Here's a good example of this (kinda old though): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xpmq-VlcZow

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! As mentioned, please do not post multiple questions (especially very distant ones) as a single question - it makes it difficult for the answerers to properly address the question, and for our voters to properly address answers. And, well, as it seems, your questions appear to be duplicates, which is a separate unfortunate scenario of its own.

Answer (score 2):

1) Cheese is a very loosely defined term, and feeding strats are used all the way up through high masters for 2v2. Some people considering feeding cheesy, others do not. There is no set answer for this.

2) As far as your promotion, it is either a case of your MMR (matchmaking rating) not being high enough to be promoted yet, or another case in the suspicious tale of the locked ladder. See [this thread on team liquid](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=224922) or [my answer to this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22224/league-promotions-halted-when-grandmaster-is-re-calculated/22835#22835) for some more details on that.

Answer (score -3):

1. It's OK and it's not a cheese (in short 'cheese'  is a strategy when you rely on random chance and you have no backup plan)
2. you'll probably will be promoted to next league in next season - there are no promotions during ladder season.

Comment: I would say a cheese is more inline of hidden proxy bases, but could be strategic and not really random chance - no backup plan implies an "all in". And it is very possible to be promoted (or demoted) mid season, please refer to the articles in the question I linked.

Comment: The general accepted definition of cheese is a strategy which sacrifices long-term play for a quick win.  If your cheese fails, generally you will lose the game.  Has nothing to do with random chance (unless you consider your opponent scouting the cheese as random chance).  And promotions are most certainly possible during the season.  Just not once they have locked it during the last couple weeks of play.